# how to plot a pie chart in d3 by giving an local geojson file as an input

Tags: json, d3.js, charts

Here is the content in geojson file

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "profit": 326,
        "npa": 174.000000
    }
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "profit": 1762,
        "npa": 1683.000000
    }
}]
}
```

I am storing the data in a myfile.geojson. I want to give this local geojson file as an input and display the pie chart based on the value profit. Thanks in advance

Here is the [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/ed3tukwx/) in which pie chart is displayed, the data of geojson file was directly stored in a variable and plotted the pie chart.

Comment: [click here for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/henbox/ed3tukwx/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `d3.json` to read in geojson. In your js, call d3.json with the following:

```
d3.json("myfile.geojson", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    pie_ready_data = data.features;
    console.log(pie_ready_data)
    // Set up the pie chart
    pie(pie_ready_data);
    // Now draw the DOM objects
});
```

Using `data.features` ensures that the `pie` variable is passed an array of `features`

See [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kvf3wK3twOGfUhix5yuZ) for the full example (including myfile.geojson as an external data source): http://plnkr.co/edit/Kvf3wK3twOGfUhix5yuZ

Comment: I've updated the plunk to actually draw the pie chart (previously it was just demonstrating how data for the chart could be retrieved). Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. i didn't acknowledge that. Thanks.